# Expanded StrSubstitute

Tags: expansion, xstring

I am trying to use `\StrSubstitute`, but what I want is to expand it all the way to get the result string.

```
\StrSubstitute{Řepa}{Ř}{Rzzz}
```

then i use it with

```
% somehow define \a as the result string of the above macro
% \def\b{Strom}

\pdf@strcmp{\a}{\b}
```

I want to use it to bypass the fact that czech characters are after A-Z which does not reflect how czech people order the characters in their alphabet

Comment: In what context do you want to use this?

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. Should have thought about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

All [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) macros starting with `\Str` accept one last optional argument in brackets `[ ]` where the resulting *expandable* output is stored in.

Your problem could been solved with

```
\StrSubstitute{Řepa}{Ř}{Rzzz}[\a]
```